# Algebraic number ring and monogenic field for finitely many primes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $O$ is its algebraic number ring. For which $K$, the following holds: for every positive integer $n$, there always exists $x \in O$, s.t $[O:\Bbb Z[x]]<\infty$ and $([O:\Bbb Z[x]],n)=1$ ?  Is this equivalent to $K$ is monogenic?

An example that not satisfies such property is given by the unique cubic subfield of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ where $p= 1 \text{(mod} 3), 2 \in \Bbb F_p^3$.